How do I fix :grep leaving garbled output on my screen?
I've been learning about :grep, and I'd like to suppress its output and view it in a quickfix window instead as many seem to suggest. However, it seems that whenever grep produces too much output, it fills the window, and I'm unable to make the unwanted output go away without manually <C-l>.
Things I've tried:

silent grep! test -R .  does not suppress grep output for some reason, output fills the screen

execute 'silent grep! test -R .' | copen The quickfix window opens, and some parts of the screen remain with my original window contents; however, all the indentations are filled with grep output, and remain until <C-l>

silent! execute 'silent grep! test -R .' | redraw | copen | redraw has the exact same behaviour as above


Running :set grepprg? yields grepprg=grep -n $* /dev/null. And :version yields VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 Included patches: 1-2116.
Distro: NixOS
This seems to reproduce on vim -u NONE.
This only seems to occur when the grep output is more than one screenful; less than that, grep output is suppressed without issue.
I'm using kitty. On the other hand, I had set my TERM to xterm-256color, I guess for some compatibility reasons? Perhaps that may be related.

Funny. I cannot reproduce. Can you include the output of :version as well? What distro are you on? You mention something about "too much output"; how much is too much?

Check out this gist.

@romainl I think your gist explains why this is happening. This bit of your gist ... is the fact that Vim executes the command in Vim's parent shell. This has a few consequences ... seems to explain the issue. Your gist even provides a solution; it should be the answer.

By default, Vim prints grep's output with "Press ENTER or type command to continue" on the bottom. That's the expected (default) behavior and pressing enter should make the output disappear. Does it? If yes, I simply misread your question.

@Friedrich Yes, such a prompt appears, but even after dismissing the prompt with ENTER, the rest of my screen is cluttered with the garbled output of grep. This is explained by the section from romainl.

I don't think it is ... pressing enter should make it go away. AFAIK, you can provoke this behavior e.g. by misconfiguring grepprg (which isn't the case, here). Anyway, I'm glad I understood your question correctly and I have no idea what's causing it :-D

@Friedrich I'm convinced that my behaviour is explained by this section of the gist ... The results are printed in the shell and clog our terminal's scroll buffer. .... This explains that the behaviour only manifests when grep output is more than a screenful. It would be unsurprisingly either if this exposed some problem in my scrollback config since I almost never use the scrollback, relying on vim's terminal scrollback.

@Friedrich done, thank you.

The problem probably comes from the terminal emulator terminfo entry. I don’t have this problem either. What terminal are you using?

@D.BenKnoble I'm using kitty. On the other hand, I had set my TERM to xterm-256color, I guess for some compatibility reasons? Perhaps that may be related.

The problem mentioned in my gist:

The results are printed in the shell and clog our terminal's scroll buffer.

is different from the one you describe:

such a prompt appears, but even after dismissing the prompt with ENTER, the rest of my screen is cluttered with the garbled output of grep.

The former is not a "problem" per se. It is just how Vim has been working for decades: grep's output is printed in Vim's parent shell and you must press <CR> to come back cleanly to Vim. I never found that mechanism as refined as I wanted it to be, hence the "solution", but it is not unusable at all.
The latter is a real problem. The tricks in my gist should solve it but not directly. Something (or a combination of things) in your setup is behaving weirdly and bypassing both the terminal emulator and the shell effectively hides it, but the problem is still there and, IMO, needs fixing.
I would start by checking if the bad behavior also happens in other terminal emulator/shell/$TERM combinations.
FWIW, the proper $TERM for Kitty is xterm-kitty, not xterm-256color. I would set that correctly before even trying different combos.

I would be curious to know how you managed to solve your problem with the information included in this overblown comment.

I only switched to cgetexpr system(...)commands as your gist explained. I wasn't bothered to try to fiddle with my TERM settings at the moment; I believe I had set it this way for some reason, and since I use vim as my terminal multiplexer, basically nothing else writes to my terminal without going through vim, and the scrollback etc inside vim's terminals work perfectly fine for me. I will note that under my main setup, I see that ENTER after :grep! leaves the screen intact, but ENTER after :silent! grep! leaves garbled text on the screen stubbornly, requiring a manual refresh to clear.
